# Static Functions / Classes.. Reasonsing?

Tags: php, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use static methods in a class and what are the benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080150/when-should-i-use-static-methods-in-a-class-and-what-are-the-benefits)

I'm working in PHP right now.

I'm working on two groups of Functions.

I have a class which consists of Date Handling Functions.

In this class I have no need for properties as each function/method is more or less a utility. As such I have made my class' functions all static.

I have a couple questions from here.

1) What benefits are there from using Static methods? I understand that there is lower processing overhead because there is not an Object. I've also heard this is negligible (depending).

2) What other types of functions/methods would be good candidates for "static" besides utilities?

Thanks

Comment: Please search before asking next time:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080150/when-should-i-use-static-methods-in-a-class-and-what-are-the-benefits
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299712/why-should-we-use-static-calls-in-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316800/when-to-use-static-modifier-in-php

Comment: Your question reads like you're at a similar level of development/knowledge with PHP as myself. Can't recommend 'PHP and MySQL - Beyond the Basic' by Kevin Skoglund - fairly cheap from Lynda.com. Really helped me understand the concepts of public/private/static methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key concept of using static methods is that they are bound to a class, not an *instance* of the class.  A good guideline is that **anything requiring state is not suitable to being used statically*.

Utility methods are definitely a good candidate for static usage, as they are often short and require no state.  Some other guidelines might be:

- Input and output are not reliant on anything except each other.
- The method has no context, that is, it doesn't make sense to associate it with an instance of an object.
- A method/variable requires no differentiation between objects, and a single declaration is all that is required.  This applies mostly to static class variables, such as a counter that is shared across all instantiated objects.